# How to get Tensorflow Embedding Projector to work with images

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

After reading the documentation [here] and  [here] [1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/README.md) [2](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/tensorboard_projector_plugin), I have been unable to get my embedding to populate the Tensorflow Embedding Projector. I am working with image data and want to visualize the embeddings, but after saving the weights and the labels to /log_dir Tensorboard still says no data was found. Any help would be appreciated.
This is copy pasted from a notebook so I apologize for any formatting errors.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
from tensorboard.plugins import projector 

def _normalize_img(img, label):
 img = tf.cast(img, tf.float32)
 return (img, label)


( X_train, y_train), (X_test,y_test) = datasets.cifar10.load_data()
train_dataset, test_dataset = tfds.load(name="cifar10", split=['train', 'test'], as_supervised=True)

# Build your input pipelines
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(1024).batch(32)
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(_normalize_img)

test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(32)
test_dataset = test_dataset.map(_normalize_img)


model = tf.keras.Sequential([
 tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(32,32,3)),
 tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),
 tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
 tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu'),
 tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),
 tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
 tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=None), # No activation on final dense layer
 tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.l2_normalize(x, axis=1)) # L2 normalize embeddings

])


# Compile the model
model.compile(
 optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
 loss=tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss(),
 metrics = ["accuracy"])

# Train the network
history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=3)




# Set up a logs directory, so Tensorboard knows where to look for files
log_dir = '/logs/test-example/'
if not os.path.exists(log_dir):
 os.makedirs(log_dir)

# Save Labels separately on a line-by-line manner.
with open(os.path.join(log_dir, 'metadata.tsv'), "w") as f:
for label in y_train:
 f.write("{}\n".format(label[0]))

# Save the weights we want to analyse as a variable. Note that the first
# value represents any unknown word, which is not in the metadata, so
# we will remove that value.
weights = tf.Variable(model.layers[0].get_weights()[0][0:])

# Create a checkpoint from embedding, the filename and key are
# name of the tensor.
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(embedding=weights)
checkpoint.save(os.path.join(log_dir, "embedding_ckpt"))

# Set up config
config = projector.ProjectorConfig()
embedding = config.embeddings.add()

# The name of the tensor will be suffixed by `/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE`
embedding.tensor_name = "embedding/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE"
embedding.metadata_path = 'metadata.tsv'

projector.visualize_embeddings(log_dir, config)

%load_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir /logs/test-example/
```